# MySQL for removing back to back duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where there is some duplicate file access information where a duplicate file access is defined as the same user accessing the same file back to back.  In other words, if the user accesses file A,B,A in that order, it's NOT considered a duplicate.  So basically, per user I want to make sure that every subsequent access is for a file different from the last one.

```
UserID  FileID
1       1
2       1
1       1   <-  Remove
2       1   <-  Remove
2       2
1       2
2       2   <-  Remove
1       1
1       2
```

Anyone know how to approach something like this in mysql?  Ideally, I would like to use it without the use of a function but I'm open to a function if it's the only option.

The table has the following columns:  ID (primary key), userID, fileID, accessTime

Comment: I think you need to re-evaluate your design so that you don't need to do this type of excercise.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on this table?

Comment: Unless there's a timestamp column on this table you are out of luck.  Tables in SQL have no implicit order, and without a unique sort key the engine is free to return the rows in any order.

Comment: Row-to-row comparisons of the type you describe are hard (or impossible) to do in pure SQL.  You will probably have to write a stored procedure or use application code to resolve this.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention that.  There is both a primary key and a timestamp column on the table.   To take it a step further, I was able to avoid this problem while this data was being collected transactionally by checking the last log in the db for that userID and rejecting "duplicates."  The problem now is, I'm doing it with in a single batch and mysql's LOAD FILE is not allowing me to inject any logic that looks as existing data from the table.

Comment: njk, what I'm doing is actually parsing Apache logs.  I'm pretty sure there are ways to do this using Perl or some other script, but I'm trying to see if I can do it in the db before I move on to those alternatives.

Comment: @Nefsu I can't think of any way to accomplish this with a standard delete SQL statement. Maybe some of the smart people here have a fancy SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you made a SPROC it would look something like this. You may need another temp table and loop as the DELETE statement may fail while the cursor is open.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_CURSOR` ()  
BEGIN  
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE lastUserAccess;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT userId, fileId, pkId FROM table1 ORDER BY time_stamp;  
    DECLARE a, b, c, d INT;  
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET a = 1;  
    OPEN cur1;  


    WHILE a = 0 DO  
        FETCH cur1 INTO b, c, d;

        SELECT fileId FROM lastUserAccess WHERE userId = b

        IF fileId IS NULL THEN
            INSERT INTO lastUserAccess (b, c, d);
        ELSE
            IF fileId = c THEN
                DELETE FROM table1 WHERE pkId = d;
            ELSE
                UPDATE lastUserAccess SET fileId = c WHERE userId = b;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;  

    CLOSE cur1;  
END
```

Answer (score 0):

For mysql

```
DELETE a from  tbl a , tbl b WHERE a.Id>b.Id and
a.UserID = b.UserID and a.FileID= b.FileID;
```

Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aece0a/1

Wont work in mysql, for sql server

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID) 
FROM tbl GROUP BY userID, fileID)
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This only keeps the first access of a file by a user.  If the user accesses a second file and then accesses the first file again, we want don't want to count the third access as a duplicate because there was a different file accessed in between.